# Group of Isomorphisms of a Groupoid

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, groupoids

Write a careful proof that every group is the group of isomorphisms of a groupoid. In particular, every group is the group of automorphisms of some object in some category.

First can someone tell me what the question is asking me.

Secondly, the proof of what they want?

Comment: Umm...this must be a homework problem?

Comment: It's from the Aluffi textbook Chapter 0

Comment: They are asking that if you are given any group $G$, find a category $\mathfrak{C}$ and an object $O \in \mathfrak{C}$ such that the Hom set $\text{Hom}(O,O)$ is a group that is isomorphic to $G$.

Comment: The proof is fairly tautological ... since you're only dealing with a single object, your category may as well just have one object ... and the Hom set has to have an associative composition with an identity morphism and every morphism must have an inverse ... hmm, what algebraic structure at your fingertips could provide that?

Comment: Can you rephrase your last sentence?

Comment: What does that mean? It is from a book. Fine. But is it homework? If it is homework, then Michael Joyce has spelled out the solution in essentially its totality. If you're really, really stuck on parsing that last sentence and this isn't homework, then we can provide a little more.

Comment: No it isn't homework. I am working on problems from the book above.

Comment: @Michael: Nitpick: it's not asking that $\hom(O,O) \cong G$, but $Aut(O,O) \cong G$, where $Aut(O,O)$ is the submonoid of $\hom(O,O)$ of invertible morphisms.

Comment: Let $\mathfrak{C}$ be a category with a single object $O$. Define the morphisms of the object (and hence all the morphisms of the category): $Hom(O,O)$ to be the group $G$, i.e. label the arrows $O\to O$ by the group elements $g\in G$ and define composition of two arrows $g\circ f$ to be the new arrow $gf$ (the symbol you get by doing the group operation). All you have to do is check that this composition rule actually satisfies the axioms of composing morphisms in a category so that $\mathfrak{C}$ is actually a category (and that every morphism is invertible so that $Hom(O,O)=Aut(O,O)$).

Comment: @Hurkyl: Thanks, you're exactly right.  Of course, the natural solution has $\text{Hom}(O,O) = \text{Aut}(O,O)$, but, as you say, that is not required.

Comment: Can someone summary everything and post it as an answer/hint? I am loss.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are asking that if you are given any group $G$, find a category $\mathfrak{C}$ and an object $O \in \mathfrak{C}$ such that the set of invertible morphisms $\text{Aut}(O,O)$ is a group that is isomorphic to $G$.

To do so, let your category $\mathfrak{C}$ have a single object $O$ and define $\text{Hom}(O,O) = G$, with composition in $\text{Hom}(O,O)$ given by the composition in $G$.  Then the identity and associativity axioms for $G$ give you the requisite identity in $\text{Hom}(O,O)$ and the associativity axiom for $\mathcal{C}$.  Lastly, the invertibility axiom for $G$ implies every element of $\text{Hom}(O,O)$ is invertible, so $\text{Aut}(O,O) = \text{Hom}(O,O) = G$.